# jQuery to update the color of the TD cell using the css from the div inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make some jquery **run on document load** so it can grab the color of the background from the div from inside a td cell and put it as the background for the td cell.

Essentially turning the following: https://jsfiddle.net/cyztevwx/ into https://jsfiddle.net/4ocj14rq/1/

### HTML Before

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="test1" style=""><div style="background-color:#63BE7B;">227.96</div></td>
        <td class="test2" style=""><div style="background-color:#F8696B;">227.96</div></td>
        <td class="test" style=""><div style="color:blue;">227.96</div></td>
        <td class="test1" style="">227.96</td>
        <td class="test1" style="color:white;"><div style="background-color:#F8696B;">227.96</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="size">Change font size</button>
```

### HTML After

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="test1" style="background-color:#63BE7B;"><div style="background-color:#63BE7B;">227.96</div></td>
        <td class="test2" style="background-color:#F8696B;"><div style="background-color:#F8696B;">227.96</div></td>
        <td class="test" style=""><div style="color:blue;">227.96</div></td>
        <td class="test1" style="">227.96</td>
        <td class="test1" style="color:white;background-color:#F8696B;"><div style="background-color:#F8696B;">227.96</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="size">Change font size</button>
```

As you can see some td's allready have a style, some are empty. Some td's have divs and some don't, some td's have styles but not background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td div').each(function() {
        $(this).parent('td').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
    });
});
```

So, we're looping through each `div` nested inside a `td`, then assigning the `background-color` value of the `div` to its `td` parent. In case a `div` doesn't have a `background-color` set, the `td` will get a `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` value which would be equivalent to `transparent`.

If you don't want a transparent value at all, you can add a condition like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td div').each(function() {
        var bgc = $(this).css('background-color');

        if(bgc != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') $(this).parent('td').css('background-color', bgc);
    });
});
```